# Angular 6 PHP Post

Tags: angular, post

I have code like this:

```
getResources() {
        return this.http.post('/api/db.php', this.query, httpOptions)
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                console.log('Got some data: ', data, typeof(data));
            }
        );
      }
```

PHP script returning me an object like this `{name: 2}`.

How can I access property of this object ?
I have to use `map()`?

Comment: `console.log(data.name);`

Answer (score 1):

If you got an object, you can access the properties of that object via `.` notation - `object.property`

```
.subscribe(data => {
     console.log('Got some data: ', data, typeof(data));
     console.log(data.name);
});
```